# Android - Camera X - How to check if device has a Front Camera CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT

Tags: android, textureview, android-camerax

I'm working with Camera X for the first time and I can't find a way to check if a device has a front or rear camera in runtime...

I only need to use the preview I'm not capturing images so i can't use a button for it..

```
private var lensFacing = CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT

 val viewFinderConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
            setLensFacing(lensFacing)
            setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
        }.build()
```

How can I make sure that the app won't crash if the user device has no Front camera?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

Check if the device supports at least one camera with the specified lens facing:

version 1.0.0-alpha06:

```
val hasFrontCamera = CameraX.hasCameraWithLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT)
```

EDIT :

version >= 1.0.0-alpha07:

From https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera:

> hasCamera() previously provided by the CameraX class call are now
>   available via the ProcessCameraProvider

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
}

cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
    val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
    try {
        var hasCamera = cameraProvider.hasCamera(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA)
    } catch (e: CameraInfoUnavailableException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bit it doesn't work.. in camera x alpha 8 its restricted to the library

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer just after your comment. Is it working now?

Comment: Hi, this solution worked but, at least in version 1.2.2, takes some seconds to process. Any ideas how to improve that?